# NMAP probing VirtualBox Client

Tags: osx, virtualbox, nmap

Cannot seem to probe virtual guests from the virtual host.
**These guests can be probed from other devices on the same LAN/Network**, but not the host. I can understand why it might be struggling, but I am wondering if anyone ever found a way to make it work.

HOST: OSX 10.6

GUEST: FreeBSD 8 (two of them)

Edit:
Adding some finer details, I have networking set to "bridged", I can ping and regularly consume services running on TCP/IP on both guests. All of my nmap probe attempts are done from the root account on the host.

Comment: How did you configure your VM's networking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The KEXT for the network card somehow had gotten corrupt. Reloaded from the install CD and then I was able to hit the guests with various NMAP probes.

Answer (score 1):

You can't if you run the `NAT` network between VM and host,

Switch to a host-only adapter, i.e vboxnet0 (you might need to create one in the Preferences dialog)

**EDIT** You can use two interfaces anyway, I always do that

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need to re-read this page "[Introduction to networking modes](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#networkingmodes)" of VirtualBox manual.

An *guest* machine is or is not visible to the *host* according to how you configured its network interfaces in *VirtualBox settings*.

If you are in a secure network, you'd configure the guest machine network card to `Bridged networking` mode. This way the *guests* will be on the same network of the *host*.

Comment: I wasn't clear enough. The guests are bridged, both on the same network subnet, can ping and uses each others exposed network services without an issue.
Like I explained above, the explanation is not what I need, but I was looking for someone that has actually gotten around this or knows more about why it doesn't work. Have you experienced this?

Comment: Yes, sure. I use this kind of configuration to do some  demo for a network security course. The only difference is that I use a linux host. :-/

Comment: A real world example of Unix =/= Linux ;)

Answer (score 0):

Updated:

As you can ping, the next thing to find out is what happens when you use nmap just set to do a ping sweep? As this is using the very same ICMP connection, it should give you a result. If it doesn't, have a look at the permissions of the account you are using to run nmap -

On Windows, the user you are logged in as must have administrative privileges on the computer (user should be a member of the administrators group).

Comment: Yes, the host can ping the guest. I regularly consume services I have running on both guests.

Comment: @Tim - did my update help. Have you checked privileges?

Comment: I am running from OSX (Unix/BSD Based) running directly under the root account. I will have to check up on the nmap documentation first to see how to do the ICMP pings. I will let you know.